# When can we "safely" use extended real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, infinity

I learned that we can define [extended reals and some related arithmetic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations). I wonder when can we use these notations without worrying about consistency.

For example, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=\infty$, I can verify that 1. by definition, $\infty+\infty=\infty$; 2. using $\epsilon-\delta$ method, I can prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n+b_n=\infty$. Thus in terms of limits, it's ok to apply the addition rule to even infinite limit points.

However, what about other maths concepts I had learned? Is it always true that as long as there exists a clear definition that includes infinity (such as limits of a $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$-valued function), then all rules that apply to finite numbers (such as addition of limits) also apply to infinity? If not, do I need to check every time by myself?

Comment: $\infty + \infty = \infty$ and $\infty \cdot \infty = \infty$ are fine, past that it gets messy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form for a list of what doesn't work.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, but you may also be interested in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4097209/26369) to [When do we cannot split an improper integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3854034/26369) which spells out many cases of to what extent limit laws do and do not work with $\infty$ around.

Answer (score 2):

All of the limit laws work just as well as before. If $l$ and $m$ are extended real numbers, and $f(x)\to l$, $g(x)\to m$ as $x\to a$, then

- $(f-g)(x)\to l-m$
- $(f+g)(x)\to l+m$,
- $(f\cdot g)(x)\to l\cdot m$,
- $(f/g)(x)\to l/m$,

*provided that those expressions to the right of $\to$ are defined.* Remember that $\infty-\infty$, $0\cdot\infty$, $\infty/\infty$, and $l/0$ are undefined.

This is no accident. In fact the reason that it makes sense to define $\infty+\infty$ as $\infty$ is that the "sum limit law" still holds under this definition. Contrariwise, since there is no way of defining $\infty-\infty$ to make the "subtraction limit law" work out, we ought to leave this expression undefined.

More deeply, one of the motivations behind the extended reals is to extend the usual arithmetic operations such as $+$ and $\cdot$ to $\pm\infty$ by continuity. The usual addition function $+:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ can be continuously extended to the point $(\infty,\infty)$, and so this is what we do.

A caveat: in measure theory and probability, I believe it is common to define $0\cdot\pm\infty=0$, even though this is not a continuous extension of multiplication. I have no doubts that this convention must be useful for other reasons, but I do not know what they are.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that limit laws still hold. I'm mostly concerned with other situations and, as you mentioned, things like $0\cdot \infty$ in measure theory.

Comment: @DanielMendoza: Sorry, I think I misread your question. There is no general principle that allows you to "transfer" true statements about the reals to the extended reals, nor is there a principle that allows you to transfer statements in the other direction. So you do have to check things individually. Some things might hold for the reals, but not for the extended reals, and vice versa. Examples: in the extended reals, every set is bounded above; the real numbers are a field, but the extended reals are not, etc.

Comment: As for $0\cdot\infty$, unless you are actually doing measure theory, I would suggest that it is better to leave it undefined. Otherwise, you are just introducing exceptions to the limit laws for no good reason.